# AWS Route 53 "Failure: DNS resolution failed: Rcode NXDomain(3)"

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

AWS Route 53 / S3 static website

I have a domain / Route 53 hosted zone with several A records. One A record in particular has started producing the error "Failure: DNS resolution failed: Rcode NXDomain(3)" when it attempts to resolve.

```
user.samtec-atg.com
```

This is a static website hosted on S3. The S3 link works, but configuring a recordset for this link using either an Alias or CNAME produces the error "Failure: DNS resolution failed: Rcode NXDomain(3)"

Again, I have several S3 websites with the same root domain, but only this link is producing the error.

How can I get this resolved?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did it start working again. About the time you posted this we were getting DNS issue on all our servers and we had changed nothing. Then about 30 minutes everything started working again.

Comment: Yes...er..no.  I tried changing name servers, and then found out that this was a wrong move, so switched them back.  When that happened the website began working again.  But this morning I am now getting the same 503 error.  I have opened another case with AWS.

Comment: Ours just started working after about 30 minutes, we did nothing on either end, so I think there was something wrong at Amazon that corrected itself.

Comment: Seems like our problem was internal.   Because the website was "new", our firewall was flagging it as potentially malicious, so it was blocked...yet somehow it got thru over the weekend....   Regardless, our IT guy white-listed my domain and I haven't experienced the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As this is the very first item in Google's Search result upon googling the @subj and it has no clear answer, I decided to excavate it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/get-health-check.html says:

> If you want to check the health of weighted, latency, or failover resource record sets and you choose to specify the endpoint only by FullyQualifiedDomainName, we recommend that you create a separate health check for each endpoint.

So, if you're routing traffic to resources that you can't create `alias records` for, such as EC2 instances, you create a record and a health check for each resource. Then you associate each health check with the applicable record. Health checks regularly check the health of the corresponding resources, and Route 53 routes traffic only to the resources that health checks report as healthy.

I've ran into this when I tried to perform a health check on on domain name in my private zone in route 53 (instead separate health check for each record/ec2-instance).

Answer (score -1):

It was recognized that your DNS was hosting in two parents so it was reject